# ReportViewer - Is it possible to show certain parameters and not others?

Tags: c#, reporting-services, reportviewer

In the ReportViewer control I have the ShowParameterPrompts property set to true so the user can adjust the parameters as they like but there are certain parameters that I want to specify programmatically and not give the user any control over. For example some tables may contain data from multiple companies and I only want to show a company their own data.

Is there a way to show the parameter prompts but just hide selected ones? I know I could create my own fields on the asp webpage to have the user enter parameters into and then just programmatically forward the values and not show the prompts, but I'm hoping to avoid that as I am showing multiple reports from the same control and it's just a lot easier if SSRS can manage showing the appropriate prompts for each report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Report Parameter Properties]

In the `.rdl` file, you can just set the parameter's visibility using the `Report Parameter Properties` dialog.

So, you can now programmatically send values for the hidden parameters and for the visible parameters, you can either programmatically set them or
prompt the user to set them.